# Adding JPanel to JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jlabel

I'm trying to add a JLabel to a JPanel to a JFrame. I set the border for the JPanel, but all I see on the JFrame is a small black square in the center of my frame. Whatever I do I can't change the size or location of it. Please help.

```
    Start main = new Start();
    Random random = new Random();

    JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("MainFrame");
    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    JLabel welcomeLabel = new JLabel();

    mainFrame.add(main);
    mainFrame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    mainFrame.setTitle(names[random.nextInt(names.length)]);
    mainFrame.pack();
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    mainFrame.setSize(mainFrameX, mainFrameY);
    mainFrame.setResizable(false);
    mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    mainFrame.add(mainPanel);

    mainPanel.add(welcomeLabel);
    mainPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
    mainPanel.setSize(new Dimension(200, 200));

    welcomeLabel.setFont(new Font("Verdana", 1, 20));
    welcomeLabel.setLocation(100, 100);

    main.start();
```

Answer (score 2):

Suggestions:

- You will want to read the tutorial, [Laying out Components](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html), as it will explain how to code with the Swing layout managers, and this information is essential to solve your current problem.
- One caveat: I urge you to avoid the temptation to use the null layout as use of it will lead to creation of code that is very hard to maintain or upgrade.
- Your JLabel, welcomeLabel, will of course need some text to be visible.
- Don't set it's location via setLocation(...) but again use the layout managers to do the dirty work of placing and sizing your components.
- You will also want to call pack() and setVisible(true) on your JFrame after adding all initial components.

Answer (score 0):

Hovercraft is right (+1), make sure you understand how the layout managers are working.

The order in which you do things are important, especially when dealing with the top level containers...

```
Start main = new Start();
Random random = new Random();

JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("MainFrame");
JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
JLabel welcomeLabel = new JLabel();    

welcomeLabel.setFont(new Font("Verdana", 1, 20));

mainPanel.add(welcomeLabel);
mainPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));

// Do this first
mainFrame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
mainFrame.setTitle(names[random.nextInt(names.length)]);

// Add your components
mainFrame.add(main);
mainFrame.add(mainPanel);

// Prepare the window for showing, now you have some content.
mainFrame.setResizable(false);
mainFrame.pack();
mainFrame.setVisible(true);
mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

main.start();
```

This will still only produce a small black square in the window, because the `JLabel` has no content and therefore it's preferred size is going to be (something like) 2x2 (because of the border).

Try adding some text to...

```
welcomeLabel.setText("Welcome");
```

And then see the difference